# selecting region of interest

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to develop an automatic brain tumor segmentation algorithm. I am currently using "**Bounding Box Method Using Symmetry**" algo, proposed by **B. Saha, N. Ray, R. Greiner, A. Murtha, H. Zhang**. I have improved and extended their code to a great deal and can now successfully segment out the tumor (decent quality) automatically.

However, the code provided by them had one drawback. If the tumor was dark then it detects the wrong side.[image: dark tumor]

Can anyone provide a suggestion, programmatically/theoretically, how should I tackle this problem.

Comment: You can try doing some little exam after the step of the auto detection, to verify that you catch the tumor. It can be done by check the homogeneity of the histogram of the region of interest. It seems that the tumor region is less homogeneous than the healthy tissue.

Comment: @Adiel do you mean using **graycoprops** ??

Comment: I didn't know this function, but seems that it may help.

Comment: @Adiel thanks a ton.. It is working. Can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Great! I see you already posted the answer... good luck!

Comment: @Adiel yes, but i just posted the code, real answer was your comment. If you would provide that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment (and write again here for future Q/A) :

You can try doing some little exam after the step of the auto detection, to verify that you catch the tumor. It can be done by check the homogeneity of the histogram of the region of interest. It seems that the tumor region is less homogeneous than the healthy tissue.

Note that it depends on the general properties of your image. Sometimes also regular tissue in the brain can has low homogeneity (like in "image2" on the file that you attached before the edit).

Comment: yes, I am now figuring out that problem ;) but you gave me ideas. I think some poking here and there might solve the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

in your code, region of interest area image itself is detecting wrong area, so there might be issue with value of lower and upper bound of area. If you can provide code so suggerstion can be more accurate.

example code:

```
# Normalize the intensity using histogram equalization
normalized_image = cv2.equalizeHist(image)

# Fine-tune these parameters based on your images
lower_bound = 100
upper_bound = 200

# Apply adaptive thresholding with adjusted bounds
adaptive_threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(normalized_image, 255,
                                           cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                                           cv2.THRESH_BINARY,
                                           blockSize=11, C=2)

# Apply a binary mask to focus on the region of interest
roi_image = cv2.bitwise_and(normalized_image, normalized_image, mask=adaptive_threshold)
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion provided by @Adiel was perfect, so real thanks to him. However, I am providing the code here to find and compare the **Homogeneity** of two images (Matlab's code). This might help others like me.

```
homogeniety1= graycoprops(uint8(left),'Homogeneity');  %left box of image
homogeniety2= graycoprops(uint8(right),'Homogeneity'); %right box of image


homogeniety1 = struct2cell(homogeniety1); % converting the homogeniety struct to
homogeniety2 = struct2cell(homogeniety2); % cell (help to get value in the struct)


if homogeniety1{1}<homogeniety2{1} % finally comparing the value
// some stuff
end
```